# five line hamburger, pure css

Tags: html, css, menu, hamburger-menu

I am trying to create a five line "hamburger" (more like a triple decker hamburger) menu using pure css and div's like this, but with five lines instead of just three:

(I really don't want to change up the approach unless you have the complete code to do so. Else please stick with divs. thanks!)

EDIT1: Note `ibm.com` has a four line hamburger. I want 5 lines. Any suggestions?

```css
/* CORE STYLES */

 :root {
  --primary-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  --secondary-color: rgba(112, 48, 160) --overlay-color: rgba(24, 39, 51, 0.85);
  --menu-speed: 0.75s;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 3rem;
}

.showcase {
  background: var(--primary-color);
  color: #fff;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.showcase:before {
  content: '';
  /* background: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/533923/pexels-photo-533923.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260') no-repeat center center/cover;*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.showcase .showcase-inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.showcase h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.showcase p {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  background: var(--secondary-color);
  color: black;
  padding: 0.75rem 1.5rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}


/* MENU STYLES */

.menu-wrap {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu-wrap .toggler {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  /* was 50px */
  height: 100px;
  /* was 50px */
  opacity: 0;
}

.menu-wrap .hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 60px;
  /* orginal 60px */
  height: 60px;
  /* orginal 60px */
  padding: 1rem;
  background: var(--primary-color);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* Hamburger Lines - Top */

.menu-wrap .hamburger>div::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
}


/* Hamburger Lines - Middle */

.menu-wrap .hamburger>div {
  position: relative;
  flex: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: purple;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}


/*Hamburger Lines - Bottom*/

.menu-wrap .hamburger>div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: green;
}


/* Moves Line Down */

.menu-wrap .hamburger>div::after {
  top: 10px;
}


/* Toggler Animation */

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked+.hamburger>div {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  background: black;
}


/* Turns Lines Into X */

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked+.hamburger>div:before,
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked+.hamburger>div:after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  background: black;
}


/* Rotate On Hover When Checked */

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked:hover+.hamburger>div {
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}


/* Show Menu */

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked~.menu {
  visibility: visible;
}

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked~.menu>div {
  transform: scale(1);
  transition-duration: var(--menu-speed);
}

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked~.menu>div>div {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease 0.4s;
}

.menu-wrap .menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menu-wrap .menu>div {
  background: var(--overlay-color);
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200vw;
  height: 200vw;
  display: flex;
  flex: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.menu-wrap .menu>div>div {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 90vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
}

.menu-wrap .menu>div>div>ul>li {
  list-style: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

.menu-wrap .menu>div>div>ul>li>a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 0.4s ease;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="menu-wrap">
  <input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
  <div class="hamburger">
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="Index.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="Team.html">Team</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="AboutUs.html">About Us</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="Definitions.html">Definitions</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="HaveDoubts.html">Have Doubts?</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="ContactUs.html">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="DonateToday.html">Donate Today</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="GetInvolved.html">Get Involved</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="TheMovement.html">The Movement</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="c11.html">c11</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="TheCeosStory.html">The CEO&#39;s Story</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<img src="/images/CII_Logo.PNG" class="img_logo_big" style="width: 50%;display: block;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;" />
<header class="showcase">
  <div class="container showcase-inner">
    <h1 style="font-size:30px; color: black;">We know how to fund the "unicorn" and tame the "machine" whilst compelling people to change how they think, work, and have fun. Truly.</h1>
    <p></p>
    <p style="font-style: italic; font-size:15px; color: gray">Optimizing change for the benefit of all.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

I've tried different pseudo selectors other than `before` and `after` and tried to modify the pseudo selectors. I also tried adding more `div`s, and much more. I also tried looking up other pseudo selectors, but none of them seem to have at least 4 states. Ex: `before` and `after` is only two states so it only puts a line on top and bottom totaling 3 lines like a normal hamburger menu. I want 5 lines to match the colors I have in my logo (see my profile image).

Yes, I am aware of the fact that a 5 line hamburger menu is non-standard...that is the point. It's about marketing.

Note: This question was posted before, but I can't find it anymore.

EDIT2: Cybersecurity is extremely important due to the content and subject of the website. I am trying not to introduce scripting to my website if that is possible, hence the css only solution. However, if other types of solutions do not introduce vulnerabilities at all, please post an answer. Thanks!

EDIT3: I searched SO with and without the `hamburger-menu` in many different ways. Not sure how to make this question more "well researched". Suggests and feedback welcome in comments.

Comment: Why not use SVG for this? What's the advantage from using CSS and semantic meaningless divs here?

Comment: Hover your mouse cursor over the downvote button. Those are some valid reasons to downvote. See also [ask]. See also [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252677/215552).

Comment: @HereticMonkey - Thanks. One reason is that I didn't research. I did and I put is in there. See the paragraph that starts with: "I've tried different pseudo". Note, I have limited exposure to web development. I am winging it. I'll delete this comment later if it helps. Learning here. The other downvote says it's not useful. How does that person know this isn't useful to me? They don't know my marketing needs. This is about marketing, but I have to code to get it. That is the point of a website usually. Please provide me with feedback if you have the time. Thanks again! Helpful!

Comment: @cloned - I've never heard of SVG. I am using CSS only because I don't want to introduce scripts in be website implementation. It's less secure. The mission requires extreme caution unless I get enough donations or a volunteer to handle my cybersecurity implementation/protection. I would love to see a SVG solution if you or someone else has one if it does not introduce cybersecurity vulnerability. I'll add this to my question so people don't waste time. thanks!

Comment: The purpose of Stack Overflow is to create a library of questions and answers that are useful to as many people as possible. So if someone downvotes a question as "not useful" they could be saying it's not useful to them, or they could be saying they don't think it's useful to many other people besides you. The fact that the answer would be useful to you is a given -- otherwise you wouldn't ask. As far as research, evidence of research beyond "I searched for stuff". For instance, [there's a whole tag for hamburger-menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hamburger-menu)...

Comment: @HereticMonkey - Thanks. I get it. I thought it would be helpful to others. IBM.com has a  4 line hamburger. I wasn't aware of a hamburger-menu tag. I'll try to add it to my question and see what happens. I'll also add some research to the question. That was just a sample to satisfy the question requirements...failed there. lol  thanks again.  Updates coming...

Comment: @HereticMonkey - I searched, with and without the `hamburger-menu`, on SO all sorts of different ways and I don't see anything remotely related to a four or five line hamburger that seemed useful. I don't know what to add to my question to make it "well researched". There just doesn't seem to be anything remotely related. Feedback and suggests welcome. I'll do the research.

Comment: SVG is a vector image type, not a script. It's also a very good solution to your problem. (A quick web search would have gotten you there) So to repeat what @Cloned asked, why does it need to be HTML and CSS?

Comment: @BryceHowitson - it doesn't. I just wasn't aware of SVG. I'm looking at SVG now here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/svg/svg-hamburger-menu/   Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Hamburger should be the same no matter the amount of lines you choose it to have. 
I would go about it by simply creating one `div` for each line.
So the `html` code would look like this:

```html
<div class="hamburger">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see I have given each div the class of line, which will be used to give each line the styling in `css`.

The `css` for actually creating visible lines would look like this:

```css
.line {
  width: 65px;
  height: 5px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 8px;
}
```

This defines the style for each individual line and with the `margin` attribute you control the distance between the lines (depending on the position or other factors you might want to split it up to the specific sides).

If you wanted to have each line in a different color you could add another class for each individual line.
e.g.

```html
<div class="line one"></div>
<div class="line two"></div>
<!-- and so on... -->
```

This would also allow you to then go on rotate each line individually like I saw you want to do using transform.
For this you then could use javascript to add a class "open" to the lines after the hamburger is clicked. This way you can add `display: none` to some and let two of them transform to form an X.
Hope that I could help you out

Comment: I don't know how to implement the transform part off the top of my head, but I'll try this or the svg solution in the comments soon. thanks!